# Tying OnAppearing() to Command in ViewModel in .NET MAUI App

Tags: maui

I'm trying to tie the `OnAppearing()` event to a command in my view model using `CommunityToolkit.Maui` but the page keeps telling me it can't find the command I'm pointing to. What am I doing wrong here?

Here's the page:

```
<ContentPage
   ...
   xmlns:mct="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
   xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
   x:DataType="vm:MyViewModel">
   <ContentPage.Behaviors>
      <mct:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Appearing" Command="{Binding InitAsync}" />
   </ContentPage.Behaviors>
...
</ContentPage>
```

I'm not doing much in the code behind of the page but here it is:

MyPage.xaml.cs:

```
MyViewModel _vm;
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{
   public MyPage(MyViewModel vm)
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      _vm = vm;
      BindingContext = _vm;
   }
}
```

MyViewModel code:

```
public partial class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   ...
   public async Task InitAsync()
   {
      // Do stuff here...
   }
}
```

Where's the problem here?

Comment: `InitAsync` is a method, not a command

Comment: I tried adding `[RelayCommand]` using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm but that didn't work either

Comment: I can't comment on that since you haven't posted the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use OnAppearing inside the ViewModel file, you can use the Maui Community Toolkit.

```
 <ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <mct:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding AppearingCommand}" EventName="Appearing" />
        <mct:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding DisappearingCommand}" EventName="Disappearing" />
 </ContentPage.Behaviors>
```

and in your ViewModel

```
        [RelayCommand]
        void Appearing()
        {
            try
            {

                // DoSomething
           
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        void Disappearing()
        {
            try
            {

                // DoSomething
           
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`[RelayCommand]` would generate `InitCommand`.

The needed xaml is `"{Binding InitCommand}"`.

See this sentence in a note in [RelayCommand attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/relaycommand):

> ... Additionally, for asynchronous methods, the "Async" suffix is also stripped before "Command" is appeneded [sic].