# How to load data from parameter on MAUI page load

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

I am navigating to a page and would like to load an object from an ID. Currently this is just "loaded" from a list, but in future will be from a database.

This is the query passing code from page 1:

```cs
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(HabitPage)}?Id={_Habit.id}");
```

Which is received by the following view and associated view model:

```cs
public partial class HabitPage : ContentPage
{
    public HabitPage(HabitViewModel habitViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = habitViewModel;
    }
}
```

```cs
[QueryProperty("Id", "Id")]
public partial class HabitViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private int id;
      
    ...
}
```

This part works - I can bind a component to this and get the correct ID to display on the page, however that setting of the `Id` property behind `id` occurs after the constructor, etc. so I am struggling to call a method which loads the full object from the "database".

I found a few posts [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76265873/tying-onappearing-to-command-in-viewmodel-in-net-maui-app) which suggest using the `OnAppearing` method to trigger the loading of the object, however I have tried to implement that in the page code-behind and in the view model as follows and am still having no luck:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:HabitTracker.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="viewModels:HabitViewModel"
             x:Class="HabitTracker.Views.HabitPage"
             Title="Habit"
             Padding="10">
    
    <ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
            Command="{Binding AppearingCommand}"
            EventName="Appearing" />
    </ContentPage.Behaviors>
    
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label
            Text="{Binding Habit.Name}" <!-- This is blank -->
            Style="{StaticResource habitTitle}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Id}" /> <!-- This shows up correctly -->
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

```cs
[QueryProperty("Id", "Id")]
public partial class HabitViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private int id;
    
    public HabitModel Habit { get; private set; }
    
    [RelayCommand]
    private void Appearing()
    {
        Habit = HabitRepository.GetHabitById(Id);
    }
}
```

The method gets called, the correct object is loaded and assigned to `Habit`, but the page never displays the updated value of name.

If I manually assign a value to Habit, e.g.:

```cs
public HabitModel Habit { get; private set; } = new() { Name = "Test" };
```

"Test" shows up on the page and is not replaced by the value of the loaded object.

Comment: `Habit` needs to be `Observable`

Comment: that's one way to do it - possibly the easiest.

Comment: Well that was incredibly simple... For clarity - I asked whether I needed to add the `[ObservableProperty]` to `Habit` which has indeed worked (I deleted the comment thinking that I could just test that for myself)

Answer (score 0):

Inheriting HabitModel from `ObservableObject` should also solve the problem:

```cs
public class HabitModel : ObservableObject
{
    //properties
}
```

You can check my answer of this case: [Maui App - Page is not updating observable property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77176739/19902734).